# SQL Server : combine two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 large tables, with around 25 columns each. They both contain the same sort of data but the columns are in different orders.

How can I combine these tables without having to re-arrange my query code? I'd rather not do that for a ~600 line script.

If needed, I can give an example of what it looks like but I don't really see the need.

I have so far tried;

```
SELECT * FROM [guest].table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM [guest].table2;
SELECT * FROM [guest].table1, [guest].table2;
```

I also tried inserting the data like so;

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [guest].table1 ON;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [guest].table2 ON;

INSERT INTO [guest].table1 id,  short_name,  name,  invention_title, reference,  client_id,  client_ref,  date_case_opened,  date_case_closed,  case_type,  notes,  fee_earner,  created,  last_updated,  file_location,  foreign_attorney_id,  foreign_attorney_ref,  country_code,  application_number,  filing_date,  publication_number,  invoice_currency,  publication_date,  status,  pct_application_number,  pct_case_id,  national_phase_entry,  base_number,  base_country,  base_date,  base_case_id,  divisional_date_lodged,  illustrative_image,  parent_case_id,  parent_application_number)
select id,  short_name,  name,  invention_title, reference,  client_id,  client_ref,  date_case_opened,  date_case_closed,  case_type,  notes,  fee_earner,  created,  last_updated,  file_location,  foreign_attorney_id,  foreign_attorney_ref,  country_code,  application_number,  filing_date,  publication_number,  invoice_currency,  publication_date,  status,  pct_application_number,  pct_case_id,  national_phase_entry,  base_number,  base_country,  base_date,  base_case_id,  divisional_date_lodged,  illustrative_image,  parent_case_id,  parent_application_number
FROM [guest].table2;
```

But that gives me this error:

> SQL Error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'exported_cases' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To clarify, I am exporting a database that currently exists in 2 portions, (table1 and table2). It already has the PK generated, and I am not inserting into it until it's completely exported, at which point the PK will be set to a number higher than any current PK.

(I need to keep the ID field preserved.)

Comment: Since you are inserting in Identity Column with `IDENTITY_INSERT` it requires you to mention all the Column names you are inserting to and provide a value for Identity column, Let the Identity Column generate the values, As it is your code is error prone as you can end up with duplicates in Identity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone is focusing on the insert, let me answer the select part :)

For the UNION to work, make sure you explicitly select all the columns in the same order:

```
SELECT id,  short_name,  name,  invention_title, reference,  client_id,  client_ref,  date_case_opened,  date_case_closed,  case_type,  notes,  fee_earner,  created,  last_updated,  file_location,  foreign_attorney_id,  foreign_attorney_ref,  country_code,  application_number,  filing_date,  publication_number,  invoice_currency,  publication_date,  status,  pct_application_number,  pct_case_id,  national_phase_entry,  base_number,  base_country,  base_date,  base_case_id,  divisional_date_lodged,  illustrative_image,  parent_case_id,  parent_application_number
FROM [guest].table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id,  short_name,  name,  invention_title, reference,  client_id,  client_ref,  date_case_opened,  date_case_closed,  case_type,  notes,  fee_earner,  created,  last_updated,  file_location,  foreign_attorney_id,  foreign_attorney_ref,  country_code,  application_number,  filing_date,  publication_number,  invoice_currency,  publication_date,  status,  pct_application_number,  pct_case_id,  national_phase_entry,  base_number,  base_country,  base_date,  base_case_id,  divisional_date_lodged,  illustrative_image,  parent_case_id,  parent_application_number
FROM [guest].table2
```

This result set you can use to query, insert into a new table or whatever :)

Comment: This has fixed my problem, but for future's sake I will keep trying to fix the previous problem in case somebody else needs it! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    you should not insert identity element its generated auto:

just try inserting all except id(which is your identity)
```

pls try this:

```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [guest].table1 ON;
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [guest].table2 ON;

    INSERT INTO [guest].table1 id,  short_name,  name,  invention_title, reference,  client_id,  client_ref,  date_case_opened,  date_case_closed,  case_type,  notes,  fee_earner,  created,  last_updated,  file_location,  foreign_attorney_id,  foreign_attorney_ref,  country_code,  application_number,  filing_date,  publication_number,  invoice_currency,  publication_date,  status,  pct_application_number,  pct_case_id,  national_phase_entry,  base_number,  base_country,  base_date,  base_case_id,  divisional_date_lodged,  illustrative_image,  parent_case_id,  parent_application_number)
    select id,  short_name,  name,  invention_title, reference,  client_id,  client_ref,  date_case_opened,  date_case_closed,  case_type,  notes,  fee_earner,  created,  last_updated,  file_location,  foreign_attorney_id,  foreign_attorney_ref,  country_code,  application_number,  filing_date,  publication_number,  invoice_currency,  publication_date,  status,  pct_application_number,  pct_case_id,  national_phase_entry,  base_number,  base_country,  base_date,  base_case_id,  divisional_date_lodged,  illustrative_image,  parent_case_id,  parent_application_number
    FROM [guest].table2;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [guest].table1 OFF;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [guest].table2 OFF;
```

Comment: I've added to my original post, I need to preserve the ID unfortunately.

Comment: pls try one last time..##you need to turn the option for allow  inserts ON, then insert, then turn the option OFF again,either first case (it seems no work in your case) try second one!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5yuhKR2B
This is what it gives me, I can't understand why it's skipping the set identity insert?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `Identity Specification-> Is Identity to True`

So you can't insert the auto generated primary key manually!!!

Comment: There isn't actually a primary key set, I could add another value with the same id currently. It's a database export you see, so there's nothing enforcing the PK on my export.

Comment: You need to set the `isidentity` to no and then try

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO   short_name,  name,  invention_title, reference,  client_id,  client_ref,  date_case_opened,  date_case_closed,  case_type,  notes,  fee_earner,  created,  last_updated,  file_location,  foreign_attorney_id,  foreign_attorney_ref,  country_code,  application_number,  filing_date,  publication_number,  invoice_currency,  publication_date,  status,  pct_application_number,  pct_case_id,  national_phase_entry,  base_number,  base_country,  base_date,  base_case_id,  divisional_date_lodged,  illustrative_image,  parent_case_id,  parent_application_number)
select   short_name,  name,  invention_title, reference,  client_id,  client_ref,  date_case_opened,  date_case_closed,  case_type,  notes,  fee_earner,  created,  last_updated,  file_location,  foreign_attorney_id,  foreign_attorney_ref,  country_code,  application_number,  filing_date,  publication_number,  invoice_currency,  publication_date,  status,  pct_application_number,  pct_case_id,  national_phase_entry,  base_number,  base_country,  base_date,  base_case_id,  divisional_date_lodged,  illustrative_image,  parent_case_id,  parent_application_number
FROM [guest].table2;
```

Try this without the ID.

Comment: It now inserts, although I need to preserve the ID (see my original post). Are there any workarounds?

Comment: id should be auto increment... or create a foreign key to link the table.

Comment: Only when working with the data. I'm trying to export data which requires the id to NOT change!

Comment: than change the second table id.. don't make is as auto increment.